# Multiple change() events on dependent select options on page load not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a php ajax code where I can manually select options from dropdown depending on what was selected in previous dropdown.
I have 3 dropdowns - country, state and city (state and city are disabled by default.)

What I want is to be able to repopulate the values from db when page reloads. I am able to set value in country and also enable the fields with the help of change() event. Example, onload country is selected, and state shows list of states but not selected (from db). City has nothing in it, obviously because state is not selected yet.

Note: data for states and city is pulled up using ajax which is working because it shows states on load.

Code:

```
$('#propertyCountry').val('<?= $propCountry; ?>');
$('#propertyCountry').change(); // Works until here
$('#propertyStateProvince').val('<?= $propState; ?>'); // List shows up without selction
$('#propertyStateProvince').change();
$('#propertyCity').val('<?= $propCity; ?>');
```

And these php variables have values, I have checked them. I am looking for some help.

I have checked it with `trigger('change');`, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
$('#propertyStateProvince').val('<?= $propState; ?>'); // List shows up without selction
$('#propertyStateProvince').change();
```

must be moved in the function which is executed in the ajax return code, after the state list is populated.
Then, the same pattern has to be applied in the return code, when the cities list is populated.